# Confused about Gamma distribution parameters in R

Tags: r, density-function, gamma-distribution

I would like to draw a Gama distribution in R but Im confused since it has different notations.

Mine is in the form:

$ \theta^\alpha x^{\alpha-1}e^{-\theta x} / \Gamma(\alpha) $

Let's say for example that $\alpha = 5$

Is this the correct way to represent it?:

```
curve(dgamma(x, scale=1, shape=5),from=0, to=100, main="Gamma distribution")
```

shape is $\alpha$ , im not sure what scale is or what the 'x'  does.

Thank you

Comment: A good way to make sure you understand your software is to use it to reproduce published values.  For instance, it takes only three lines of code to reproduce the PDFs plotted in the [Wikipedia article on the Gamma distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_distribution).  Why not do that and compare your results to its?

Comment: The `x` will take values evenly over the interval `from`--`to`, supply to `dgamma()` by the `curve()` function. Typically, i.e. when not used inside a call to `curve()`, `x` is the vector of values at which you want to evaluate the density of the distribution.

Answer (score 2):

Following the standard notation you should define the scale parameter as 
$1/\theta$.

Of course in this case it makes no difference because $\theta = 1$ but in general when you write the pdf of the gamma distribution the way you did, $\theta$ is called rate paramenter and not scale parameter.

This is also made clear in the R documentation for the function:

```
dgamma
```

[here](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/Rlab/versions/2.15.1/topics/Gamma)

About x insted .. "what x does" is nothing.

x represents the point where you evaluate the pdf.

If you have a sample from a gamma distribution all $x_1,x_2,...,x_n$ are your sample points.

Comment: Thank you, since I want to generate an n sample with PDF of the gamma distribution and alpha=5, theta doesnt have a fixed value so I should leave the rate parameter unspecified?  Is the following line enough? dgamma(x, alpha = 2, log = FALSE)
 I get an error when I try to generate it

Comment: I think you are a little confused here. First of all to generate a n sample from the gamma distribution you want to use rgamma() and not dgamma. As you  have been already told dgamma() evaluates the pdf at the specified point x. Hence x has to be a number. To answer the second question you necessarily need to specify both shape and scale parameters. You can leave the scale unspecified but in that case it will assume the default value of 1.

Comment: ok thank you, im still confused, If I run this command: rgamma(1000,2,1/10) It will run 1000 instances, with alpha = 2 , and theta = 1/10 ? but 1/10 of what, this is what I don't understand.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the gioxc88's answer, I have wrote the code with two plots for the gamma distibutions with a parametrization by rate $\theta = \{0.9, 1, 1.1\}$ and $\alpha=5$:

```
set.seed(1234) # set for reproducibility
n = 100

alpha = 5
theta = c(0.9, 1, 1.1)
x <- seq(0, 10, len=n)

f <- sapply(theta, function(mytheta) dgamma(x, shape = alpha, rate = mytheta))
F <- sapply(theta, function(mytheta) pgamma(x, shape = alpha, rate = mytheta))

leg <- sapply(theta, function(mytheta) sprintf("G(%.3g, %.3g)", alpha, mytheta))

par(mfrow=c(1,2))

kk <- seq(dim(f)[2]); cpal <- rainbow(max(kk))

plot(x, f[,1], col=cpal[1],
type="l", lwd=1,
xlim=c(0.9*min(x), 1.1*max(x)), ylim=c(0, 1.1*max(f)),
xlab="x", ylab="f(x)", main="PDF of Gamma distributions")

for(k in kk[-1]) lines(x, f[,k], col=cpal[k], lwd=1)
legend("topright", col=cpal, lwd=1, legend=leg)


plot(x, F[,1], col=cpal[1], type="l", lwd=1,
xlim=c(0.9*min(x), 1.1*max(x)), ylim=c(0, 1.1*max(F)),
xlab="x", ylab="F(x)", main="CDF of continuous random variables")

for(k in kk[-1]) lines(x, F[,k], col=cpal[k], lwd=1)
legend("bottomright", col=cpal, lwd=1, legend=leg)
```

[image]

Comment: `dgamma` and `pgamma` are already vectorized functions.  Thus, for instance, an expression like `curve(dgamma(x, 5, 0.9), 0, 10, col="red")` (or similar) could form the heart of your code around which you write a simple loop, as in `x <- seq(0, 10, length.out=101);
f <- list(PDF=dgamma, CDF=pgamma);
for (s in names(f)) {
  y <- outer(x, c(0.9, 1.0, 1.1), f[[s]], shape=5);
  plot(range(x), range(y), type="n", main=s, xlab="x", ylab="f(x)");
  lapply(1:3, function(i) lines(x, y[,i], col=hsv(i/3)))
}` BTW, setting the seed is pointless: you don't generate any random values.